How to Edit a Json File That is Already Built by Next.js?
Just like follow website, this page is providing data with their json file. They update the json file every three hours. Any clues to doing it?
https://www.op.gg/_next/data/A7fGXM4DrLQE_OvifwApt/en_US/champions.json?position=all&tier=emerald
